# Numbers in quotes using json_encode()

Tags: php, json

Various 3rd party companies are forcing us to use non-conventional code and produce non-standard output.

We are using standard `json_encode()` to output a JSON variable in JS/HTML which looks like:

```
"custom":{"1":2,"2":7,"3":5}
```

Now they tell us this isn't working for them, they need it this way:

```
"custom":{"1":"2","2":"7","3":"5"}
```

Can I force PHP to wrap quotes arround numbers? Maybe using cast `(string)` when we build the object before encoding?

Mainly, we need an opposite of the following option bitflag:

**`JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK (integer)`**

> ```
> Encodes numeric strings as numbers. Available since PHP 5.3.3.
> ```

But I doubt this exists.

Comment: This question is different from the linked question because it doesn't consider `json_encode()` turning strings back into numbers, see https://3v4l.org/YZS0F

Comment: @mickmackusa yea but I don't need a solution anymore as I don't work with people anymore who don't accept standards. Look at this RFC that deals with the situation in question: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/json_numeric_as_string

Comment: You ran a bad test and unjustly unhammered the dupe. https://3v4l.org/S8nXc  `array_map()` does not modify by reference.

Comment: @mickmackusa kudos! thanks for guiding me to my mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're building your json data from a one-dimensional array, you can use

```
echo json_encode(array_map('strval', $data));
```

This technique will unconditionally convert all values to strings (including objects, nulls, booleans, etc.).

If your data might be multidimensional, then you'll need to call it recursively.

Answer (score 3):

Guess you need to fix this yourself. I can't think of a built-in function, but you can write your own:

```
function stringify_numbers($obj) {
    foreach($obj as &$item)
        if(is_object($item) || is_array($item))
            $item = stringify_numbers($item); // recurse!
        if(is_numeric($item)
            $item = (string)$item;
    return $obj;
}
```

Now you can use `json_encode(stringify_numbers($yourObject))`

Comment: `stringify` is not a valid PHP function, is it? I get your concept tho, helpful to me. I was hoping for a simple bitflag that always adds quotes :(

Comment: @DanFromGermany stringify was a typo. It's fixed. It was meant to be recursive

Comment: There is a native function to recursively iterate all leafnodes: `array_walk_recursive()`. [Demo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67023516/2943403)