# Return string with leading zeros in PHP

Tags: php, leading-zero

[Similar to this unsolved question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24520950/json-numeric-check-and-phone-numbers)

My PHP output requires `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` enabled, however there is one string **nick** column in my database that needs to be returned originally as a string. Values in that column can contain numbers and there's no length restriction. Code example:

```
$response["players"] = array();
...
$stmt = $connection->prepare('SELECT id, nick FROM players WHERE NOT id = ? ORDER BY nick');
$stmt->bind_param('i', $_POST["id"]);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->bind_result($id, $nick);
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $players = array();
    $players["id"] = $id;
    $players["nick"] = $nick;
    array_push($response["players"], $players);
}
...
echo json_encode($response, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

For example, nick **"007"** is being returned as **"7"** and I need it to be the original **"007"**. Removing **"JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK"** helps, but it bugs the rest of the code. **Strval()** function used like quoted below didn't help.

```
$result = $stmt->bind_result($id, strval($nick));
$players["nick"] = strval($nick);
```

Comment: which data type is nick column ??

Comment: TINYTEXT, it doesn't matter, because the statement returns correct value

Comment: Just a suggestion, but what if you worked the other way around, that is don't use `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` and then you convert the other fields to numbers?

Comment: _“Removing "JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK" helps, but it bugs the rest of the code”_ - then the rest of the code seems to need fixing.

Comment: try like this only:- https://eval.in/974421. Also change while code like this:- `while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $response["players"] = ["id" => $id, "nick" => $nick];
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP there is unfortunately no explicit type for variables, this makes your problem not so easy to solve.

I came with 2 solution.

1) if you like OOP, make a `Serializable, Arrayable` class to use as container for your string with a method returning the right encoded value.

2) first encode using `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` in order to make sure your data is what you expect it is, then decode the validated data, manually set the string to its origina value, then encode again but this time not using `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK`.

```
$str = $response['nick'];
$response = json_decode(json_encode( $response, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK ) );
$response->nick = $str;
$response = json_encode( $response );
```

Comment: Well I'm not sure if 2) is not the same as removing JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK?

Comment: I never used it before, but if this is his requirement, that's a quick way to keep using it and push the string value in its place

Answer (score 0):

The management of numbers is strange to say the least ... 
It's almost scary !

then on PHPTESTER:

```
$CUSTOMER['id'] = 123;

$CUSTOMER['tel'] = '06 06 06 06 06';
// unbug for zero top of tel number -> json_encode

$CUSTOMER['tel'] = "".$CUSTOMER['tel'].""; 

echo json_encode($CUSTOMER, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Output : {"id":123,"tel":"06 06 06 06 06"}

On my host (same code) : Output : {"id":123,"tel":"6 06 06 06 06"} // zero was removed !

I found an unlikely solution :
I surrounded the variable with a space ...

```
$CUSTOMER['tel'] = " ".$CUSTOMER['tel']." "; // wrap with spaces
```

Output (on my host) : {"id":123,"tel":"06 06 06 06 06"}

in PHP version 5.5

Here is a solution, I would like to have your opinion, in any case it worked for me.