# How can I force PHP's json_encode integer values to be encoded as String?

Tags: php, json

I'm using PHP v5.6.

As i read that php json_encode function is automatically converting int to string. But not in my case. Json_encode is still return it to int not string.

Like example:

```
json_encode(['code' => 200, 'results' => [id=> 1]]);
```

my expected results is all become a string. but what i get is

```
{"code":200,"results":{"id": 1}}
```

Expected output:

```
{"code":"200","results":{"id": "1"}}
```

How can i change all the result become string without using "" for every value?.

NB: results array is based on query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the link posted by Thomas in comments, one user [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19687406/force-json-encode-to-create-strings#19687691) that you do this:

```
$data = json_encode(array_map('strval', $data));
```

This might not be the most efficient in terms of performace though, since every entry on the array will pass through the `strval` function.

Comment: yes. at last i got a way to use array_map and array walk properly. so it can change all the int to string automatically. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: This is only a suitable technique if the input array is guaranteed to be one-dimensional.  Otherwise, there will be problems https://3v4l.org/GcIma.

Comment: @Marcos Dimitrio thanks for your answer its works like charm.

Answer (score 0):

```
json_encode(['code' => 200, 'results' => [id=> strval(1)]]);
```

With [strval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strval.php) php will return

> The string value of var.

Comment: yes. i use strval. but its from query result. if i use strval it will be a lot of value to use strval()

Comment: @sstarlight are you affraid it might influence performance, what is exactly the problem with ` it will be a lot of value to use strval() `?

Comment: I mean. if inside results. i have 50 value. and it need to convert to strval. It will be not efficient enough.

Comment: Yes, this would be rather painstaking to manually call `strval()` on 50 columns in a result set.

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that all numeric "leaf nodes" of a potentially multi-dimensional array are cast as strings, call `array_walk_recursive()` and make conditional changes to each value type.  By checking if the value "is numeric", you prevent values like `null` and booleans from being cast as strings.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/9XYFd))

```
$array = [
    'code' => 200,
    'results' => [
        'id' => 1
    ],
    'a' => [
        [
            'b' => [
                4,
                null,
                false
            ]
        ]
    ]
];

array_walk_recursive(
    $array,
    function(&$v) {
        if (is_numeric($v)) {
            $v = strval($v);
        }
    }
);
echo json_encode($array);
```

Output:

```
{"code":"200","results":{"id":"1"},"a":[{"b":["4",null,false]}]}
```