# With json_encode, is there a way to force certain values not to be converted into numeric?

Tags: php, json, scientific-notation

When using PHP (5.4/5.5) and json_encode(), I'm having some issues when using the JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK option.  This is on a system in production, so I can't simply remove the option, as this would change the entire response and break client parsing.

Sample code:

```
$var = array("id" => 1195756, "hash" => "7e12");
echo json_encode($var) . "\n";
echo json_encode($var, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK) . "\n";
```

Output:

```
{"id":1195756,"hash":"7e12"}
{"id":1195756,"hash":7000000000000}
```

The later is not what I want.  "7e12" is a valid hash for our system.  I realize it's also loose scientific notation, but how can I force the value to stay as a string?

Note: Using [strval()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33706043/how-can-i-force-phps-json-encode-integer-values-to-be-encoded-as-string) had no effect.

Comment: JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING is it useful ?

Comment: `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` is telling it to encode numeric strings as numbers and you are passing a numeric string.  The only option is to not use `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` or don't pass a numeric string.

Comment: *"I got this working snippet and this not working snippet, how can I get the latter to work. "* - Well, use the first one.

Comment: @Onur: no, it made no difference.

Comment: Onur. That might work for this particular value, although I don't know if this value is considered 'big' enough. But integers with scientific notation (or strings appearing to be integers with scientific notation) can also evaluate to small integer values, for instance `"7e2"` in which case it certainly won't work.

Comment: JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING won't trigger with scientific notation.  If the number is actually identified as such, it's formatted with proper notation (ie. 7.0e+14), but is not a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `strval()` on the fields that should stay strings, use `intval()` or `floatval()` on fields that should be numeric. In other words, give the JSON encoder the correct types. Then, you don't need `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` to fix up things that should have been numbers to start with.

Comment: This is the direction I ended up taking, using `(int)` to force numeric data where I wanted it.  PDO/mysql returns all strings, so had to do something.