# how to add qoutes in php or javascript array ot json

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I have a php array which i json_encode to use in javascript but i need one of the to be in quotes. I do not know how to go about it. 
Here is my php array

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [label] => 03
        [value] => 2
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [label] => 05
        [value] => 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [label] => 06
        [value] => 12
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [label] => 07
        [value] => 12
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [label] => 08
        [value] => 1
    )

)
```

heres my json_encode

```
[{"label":"03","value":2},
{"label":"05","value":2},
{"label":"06","value":12},
{"label":"07","value":12},
{"label":"08","value":1}]
```

what i want is

```
[{"label":"03","value":"2"},
{"label":"05","value":"2"},
{"label":"06","value":"12"},
{"label":"07","value":"12"},
{"label":"08","value":"1"}]
```

Comment: Why do you need the value in quotes? If you require `string` data type just cast it within the PHP.

Comment: Please have in mind that if you quote the numbers the data type will be interpreded differently. a "2" is a string and 2 is a number.
You can try to explicit cast the number to a string in php.

Comment: json_encode($strings, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I force PHP's json\_encode integer values to be encoded as String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33706043/how-can-i-force-phps-json-encode-integer-values-to-be-encoded-as-string)

Answer (score 1):

Use foor loop to iterate through the array of arrays and convert every int to string.

```
for (int i = 0; i < firstArray.length; i++){
for (int j = 0; j < firstArray[i].length; j++){
    firstArray[i][j][1] = firstArray[i][j][1].toString();
}}
```

This could work for you.

And if you strictly know that you will have json object with 2 items in every item in array you could use:

`for (int i = 0; i < firstArray.length; i++){
    firstArray[i][0][1] = firstArray[i][0][1].toString(); 
    firstArray[i][1][1] = firstArray[i][1][1].toString();
}`

Answer (score 0):

In your php array you have:

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [label] => 05 (as string)
        [value] => 2 (as integer)
    )
```

`json_encode` checks the type of value that you have in this array. According to the json standard integer can be stored without quotes.

You can:

- convert integers to strings (before `json_encode`),
- or use `array_map` function in php (before `json_encode`)

something like this:

```
$data = json_encode(array_map('strval', $data)); // all variables are now strings
```

Comment: using array_map converts my array to the below Array
(
    [0] => {"label":"03","value":"2"}
    [1] => {"label":"05","value":"2"}
    [2] => {"label":"06","value":"12"}
    [3] => {"label":"07","value":"12"}
    [4] => {"label":"08","value":"1"}
) how can i convert this back to a normal array like this [1] => Array
    (
        [label] => 05 
        [value] => 2
    )

Comment: @user7498826 you need convert php array to array without quotes? or json array to php array without quotes?

Comment: basically i need to convert the array so that when i json ecode it this time i will get a json data with quotes on values..because currently when i encode it just takes away the quotes